# Upload Picture to Facebook SDK Android

Tags: android, facebook, upload, photo

I've already implemented a Facebook upload photo feature in my Android Apps, 
Everything working fine when I debug the apps in my device.

But when I try to using the Facebook feature after build my apps to APK, the photo was not uploaded

any suggestion ?

this is the code I'm using for upload photo to facebook after log in :

```
public void uploadPhoto(String path){
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("method", "photos.upload");

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

    java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream os = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
    params.putByteArray("picture", os.toByteArray());

    AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFb);
    asyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST",
            new SampleUploadListener(), null);
    //asyncRunner.request(params, new SampleUploadListener());
}
```

The photo was uploaded fine when I'm run the debug in my phone , the problem occur when test with production APK file.

Comment: Need sample code, or error msg.

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for your response , I've added the code I use to upload photo

Comment: I don't see where you are actually doing the upload.  Also, have you set the proper permissions in the manifest file.  Assuming you're doing this over a network (uses permission.INTERNET).

Comment: Hi Mike , this the function I used for the upload I use it in my C++ using the JNI. I've already uses the permissions, So what make me confuse is everything works fine when I'm debug with real device but fail to upload when I test with the production APK installed with the same device thanks

Answer (score 0):

change your debug keystore's keyhash with your release keystore's keyhash